# formula for the integral of characteristic functions of measurable sets

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Fix $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and let $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $L(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_1/a_1,\dots,x_n/a_n)$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a funtion such that there exsists a sequence  of step functions, $(h_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, such that $\|f-h_k\|_1\to 0$ (i.e. $f$ is integrable).

Now I consider $f\circ L$. If we write the step functions as follows $h_k=\sum_ic_i^{(k)} 1_{Q_i^{(k)}}$ with cuboids $Q_i^{(k)}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $h_k\circ L=\sum_ic_i^{(k)} 1_{L(Q_i^{(k)})}$, is that right?

Now, let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ measurable, i.e. the characteristic function $1_M$ is Lebesgue integrable. Very elementary, and without using that $L$ and $L^{-1}$ are continuous, how to prove that $1_{L^{-1}(M)}$ is Lebesgue integrable?  Furthermore, I have to show/conclude that $|(det(L)|\int 1_{L^{-1}(M)}dx=\int 1_{M}dx$. But before I do the second part, I need a hint for the first part. I appreciate any hints for this and a correction or a confirmation of $h_k\circ L$.

Comment: maybe you mean $\mathbf 1_{L^{-1}(Q_i)}$ instead of $\mathbf 1_{L(Q_i)}$, with this change then yes, $h_k\circ L$ is right. Im assuming here the standard notion of composition, that is generally assumed as composition by the right (in some old books it is possible that composition must be assumed by the left)

Comment: @Masacroso thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do need to note that $L$ is a homeomorphism; otherwise, $L(M)$ might not be Borel for every Borel set $M$. And you need to know the basics of how the Lebesgue measure is developed. At least, you need this in the proof I know, (adapted from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis):

Let $Q$ be any box in $R^n$, of side length $2^{-k}$. Then,

$m(L(Q))= \frac{2^{-kn}}{\prod a_i} =\frac{1}{\prod a_i}\cdot 2^{-kn}=(\det L)m(Q).$

Thus,

$\int 1_Q= \frac{1}{\det L} \int 1_{L(Q)}=(\det L^{-1})\int 1_{L(Q)}.$

This formula is true for $any$ invertible linear transformation, so we may substitute $L^{-1}$ for $L$, to obtain

$\int 1_Q=(\det L)\int 1_{L^{-1}(Q)}.$

This shows that the result is true for boxes. But then, since every open set is a countable disjoint union of such boxes, the result is also true for any open set (use the countable additivity of $m.)$ This in turn shows that the result is true for all Borel sets, and finally, since every Lebesgue meaurable set is a union of a Borel set and a set of measure zero which of course does not affect the integral, you have the formula on the whole of $\frak M.$